# JWT in httpOnly cookie - AuthGuard and protected routes (Node.js, Angular)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, jwt

I am working on my app and I am using JWT for authentication and authorization and I am trying to find the best solution for storing JWT. (In current version, I have JWT stored on server in session object)

My current solution have many problems, so I decided for different implementation - Storing JWT in httpOnly cookie on the client.

My question is, **how would I find out, if the user is logged in or not?** (I need to know this because of the AuthGuard - for protecting routes, for example `/home` should not be accesible to logged out users). Since the cookie is httpOnly, I cant verify it on client.

In current implementation, I have special route on backend just for checking, if the user have jwt in session object. But this is not great implementation - client have to send request everytime when he want to load protected route.

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: But if you store this in Local storage lets say, you can still access it via javascript. (You can set variable into local storage). And also, I probably need verify, if user is logged before even send the request.

Comment: Sorry, deleted the comments by mistake, the backend will be the master anyway. If you are directing a user to the home page, an API must fire ( on a rest-client), the API response will take care of resetting the value and giving fresh data. Storing on a browser should only make navigation faster.

Comment: BTW, it's always been my understanding that the JWT is supposed to be instead of server-side session storage. When the user logs in, the server authenticates them, puts the user's identifier and optionally, permissions, into a signed JWT and returns it to the client. Then there is no need to keep the token in session - the client holds the token, passes it to the server,  the server verifies the signature, and dentifies the user and if present, permissions, from the token itself.  This makes the server more scalable - no need for session affinity or shared sessions.

Comment: But how to store tokens on client? Local storage or cookies? Both have some disadvantages..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the expiration date of the JWT itself. Client-side you could create a loop that is constantly checking expiry (i.e.: `setInterval`).

I would **not** depend on the mere fact that a JWT token is present that the "session" is valid. Use a JWT token only to identify who the user is such as by using a UUID, random string, etc.

For each subsequent request to the API, while passing the JWT token, you should always perform validation server-side to ensure that:

1. The token envelope is valid (being signed by your secret key).
2. The unique identifier corresponds to a valid account/user.

**Do not use an `httpOnly` cookie, literally for almost anything!**
If this JWT token is leaked (i.e.: captured by the myriad of devices your http only traffic will pass through) it exposes an attack vector that allows an actor to impersonate this user session.

To answer your other question, you could store the JWT token in a medium like `localStorage`. JWT's are meant to be light weight enough where it would be expected that you send it along with each request.

Hope that helps shed some light on things for ya. Let me know if you have any more concerns or questions!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So.. basically only thing I have to do is store token in LS (I have still some concerns about it like XSS attacks..) and then use token interceptor to attach JWT into request header. Then, on the server I decode token, check if random string inside the token is equal to the token in database associated with current user. If so, I will send data to the user. But what if JWT expires? Should I make something like refresh tokens? (After JWT expires, client will automaticly send request to the /token end point for obtain new JWT). Thanks for your advices.

Comment: You should have the user re-login if it expires ;)